# Objective memory leaks when copying objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a sample app that looks like a social network iOS app. I am new to cocoa framework  so I'm studying the sample code. Upon hitting analyze, there are 255 reported memory leaks in the app. I was able to solve around 100 of the leaks which were very simple, but I cannot solve the rest.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{ 
    //DLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if([MethodName isEqualToString:@"SignInStep"])
    {

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
        { // clear out our story item caches... 
            item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            currentUserId = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

            currentError = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        } 

    }

}
```

Allocation of variables for the item:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{ 
    //DLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);

    if([MethodName isEqualToString:@"SignInStep"])
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
        { // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
            [item setObject:currentUserId forKey:@"userId"]; 

            [item setObject:currentError forKey:@"error"];

            [SignIn addObject:[item copy]];    //Method returns Objective C Object with +1 retain count 

        } 
    } 

}//Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

I received the following errors:

> 1) Method returns Objective C Object with +1 retain count
>
> 2) Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

I have mentioned in the above code where exactly I received these leaks. Can anyone tell me what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You must relinquish ownership of an object you own**

```
id obj =  [item copy];
[SignIn addObject:obj]; // SignIn will retain obj 
[obj release];
```

Take a look at [Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

```
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // release this object
        currentUserId = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // release this object

        currentError = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // release this object
```

Comment: thanks @parag Bafna. its working but i really dont understand ur code.. can u please elabrate the code

Comment: Whenyou add an object to array , it will call retain on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Every alloc, retain, copy calls should have equivalent release call.
As you are allocating item, currentUserId and currentError in didStartElement. They should be released some where,as per your code it will be mostly in didEndElement:

Remember that whenever objects are added to array or dictionary, the objects will be retained.  Those objects will be released whenever array (or) dictionary is released.

id obj =  [item copy]; // obj retaincount +1

[SignIn addObject:obj]; // obj retaincount +1

[obj release];  // obj retaincount-1

whenever SignIn is released, obj retain count will become 0.

Answer (score 0):

Some more points related to memory leaks. 
One should follow these rules to avoid memory leaks:

**You own any object you create**

You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

**You can take ownership of an object using retain**

A received object is normally guaranteed to remain valid within the method it was received in, and that method may also safely return the object to its invoker. You use retain in two situations: (1) In the implementation of an accessor method or an init method, to take ownership of an object you want to store as a property value; and (2) To prevent an object from being invalidated as a side-effect of some other operation

**When you no longer need it, you must relinquish ownership of an object you own**

You relinquish ownership of an object by sending it a release message or an autorelease message.

**You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own**

reference: [apple documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)